# Options to optin auto-implemented properties only?

Tags: fody, fody-propertychanged

I have class which are inherit base class which have it own "OnPropertyChanged" event called, eg: Xamarin BindableObject like below

```cs
public string Name {
  get { return (string)GetValue(NameProperty); }
  set { SetValue(NameProperty, value); }
}
```

is it possible to automatic (or config options) opt-out those property without using `DoNotNotifyAttribute` attribute?
and just weaving if property are auto-implemented property?

```cs
public string Name {
  get;
  set;
}
```

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. currently this is not possible